# Delphi Seattle IDE - Square bracket error

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Maybe some of you can help me... I'm using Delphi Seattle, on Windows 10, Portuguese keyboard layout (tried with English layout too), and on the Code tab (Design tab works perfectly), when I try to type: "]", this key only, it appears "["... No other keys have any problem, only this one. Any idea about what could be my issue?

Sorry if this website is not for this kind of discussion, but where I can ask this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `Use Ctrl+Alt keys` editor setting in IDE options

[image: Editor Options]

If I disable that option I can only enter `]` but can't enter `[` if I'm holding Ctrl+Alt keys. But I can enter both `[` and `]` if I'm holding AltGr key instead.

When specific option is enabled I it works both ways.

EDIT: In previous versions of Delphi like Delphi 7 for instance you had to make suitable registry change in order to change this.

EDIT2: As you already figured out by yourself the IDE enhancements modules can also interfere.

Comment: Here it was marked, I unmark, but the problem stills... I tried to enter ']', but appear '[', I tried holding Ctrl+Alt+], and AltGr+], both combinations appeared the symbol "º"...

Comment: Wait it seems I have misunderstood you the first time. You say that when you try to type in the `[` you get `]` instead. Is that correct? And if it is does it only happen in code editor or also in other parts of Delphi IDE like Object inspector (editing properties)

Comment: That is strange. What happens if you try to change the keyboard layout in Windows when Delphi is active? it is possible that Portuguese keyboard layout is so much different.

Comment: It still the same problem. And I never had this problem with Delphi... It's just strange. I'm not sure, but I think it's since when I installed the Delphi 10... Not sure about that... The portuguese layout is not that different, when I try SHIT+], I get }, what is right...

Comment: Wow, I got it working, I unchecked all that Enhancement Modules on the screen you show me and now is working... Smart Surround Keys was the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I'm Glad you found the solution to your problem. Now I suggest you try enabling those Enhancements one by one to see which one is causing the problems and report 5this to Embarcadero so they can fix it.

Comment: I have edited my answer with the solution that you found so that it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here.
To workaround I do this:.
Go to **Tools|Options|Editor|Key Mappings|Enhanced Modules** and uncheck **"Smart Surround Keys"** option.
When unchecked you will lost automatic open/close parentesis/brackets()[] in marked text, but resolv this issue.